# recursive run of rpg program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

i am running a rpg program recursively it is giving an error like this
Application Error. RNX8888 unmonitored by PGM1 at statement *N, instruction X'0000'.
Trigger program or external routine detected an error.....what can be the resolution ...its urgent..thanks

Comment: If it is urgent, then you should care even more about formatting your question properly and providing all necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

You should have more information in your job log.  There will be more details as to the exact cause of the error.
Please get this info and post it.
BTW: RPG programs cannot be called recursively.  RPG ILE programs can be called recursively. So this is probably an RPG ILE.  If it is not, then there is problem #1.

Comment: Nope, RPG ILE programs _can't_ be called recursively (although RPG ILE procedures can).

Comment: ILE RPG programs can effectively be called recursively if compiled appropriately. It's rarely a good idea for a trigger program though.